# How to control the ShowUpDown of a DateTimePicker in VB.Net

Tags: vb.net, datetimepicker

I have two DateTimePicker object in my form,

Custom Format of "hh : mm tt"

ShowUpDown = True

ex.

```
Time : 12:00
```

When I press the Up Key, I want to increase the minute value to +30

```
Time : 12:30 PM
```

Answer (score 0):

Using the event

```
DataTimePicket.KeyDown
```

Sample Usage :

**VB.NET**

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)

    dateTimePicker1.KeyDown += DateTimePicker1OnKeyUp

End Sub

Private Sub DateTimePicker1OnKeyUp(sender As Object, e As KeyEventArgs)
    If e.KeyValue = 38 Then
        ' up
        dateTimePicker1.Value = dateTimePicker1.Value.AddSeconds(30)
        e.SuppressKeyPress = True
    ElseIf e.KeyValue = 40 Then
        'down
        dateTimePicker1.Value = dateTimePicker1.Value.AddSeconds(-30)
        e.SuppressKeyPress = True
    End If
End Sub
```

**C#**

```
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        dateTimePicker1.KeyDown += DateTimePicker1OnKeyUp;

    }

    private void DateTimePicker1OnKeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.KeyValue == 38) // up
        {
            dateTimePicker1.Value = dateTimePicker1.Value.AddSeconds(30);
            e.SuppressKeyPress = true;
        }
        else if (e.KeyValue == 40) //down
        {
            dateTimePicker1.Value = dateTimePicker1.Value.AddSeconds(-30);
            e.SuppressKeyPress = true;
        }
    }
```

Comment: thankyou! It worked! But how can I apply these codes when the user Clicks the Up/Down Buttons?

Comment: by up/down btn u mean , uhave addtional Button ?

Comment: No, I set the ShowUpDown Property of the DateTimePicker to be True, it looks like the NumericUpDown component.

Comment: well seems like there is no direct way, my possible assumption is , override the **protected override void WndProc** and check for the particular Message that is fired when up/down are pressed